# Boolean Condition in FTL

Tags: java, freemarker

I am new to freemarker template . I need to display a string based on boolean condition.I get Error while parsing the ftl file

```
<#if debitNote.gst?string("Yes", "No")>
```

**Error**

```
if debitNote.gst?string("Yes", "No") [on line 150, column 95 in creditDebitCustomer.ftl]
----------

Java backtrace for programmers:
----------
freemarker.core.NonBooleanException:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ternary expression with the [`then`](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_boolean.html#ref_builtin_then) expression:

```
${debitNote.gst?then("Yes", "No")}
```

> The [`string`](http://freemarker.incubator.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_boolean.html) boolean builtin function has been deprecated since
>   FreeMarker 2.3.20 and has been replaced with `then`.

Comment: <#if {debitNote.gst?then("Yes", "No")}> like this?

Comment: No need to use `if` expression at all. Ternary expressions does the `if` statement internally.

Comment: didnt fine the if tag..My fault

Comment: Why do you still have the `if` tag? Remove the `</#if>`. You **don't** use the `if` expression when using ternary `if` expression. Also, if you are getting a different error, not relating to this problem, ask another SO question so that it can be resolved better.